# This OCaml expression has the type of its argument when it wasn't defined to AFAIK, and why this other expression have '_a rather than 'a?

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I get that

```
let apply f x = f x
```

has type

```
('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b
```

`apply` is a function that takes a function `f` and an argument `x` and returns the `f` applied to `x`. So, if `f x` has type `'b` and `x` has type `'a`, then `f` has to have type `'a -> 'b`, so you combine them to get `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`. I get that. By extension, `let identity f = f` has type `'a -> 'a` because it takes an item of type `'a'` and returns the same item of type `'a`, so it's of type `'a -> 'a`. I get that.

```
let bf b f = if (f b) then f else (fun x -> b)
```

is of type

```
bool -> (bool -> bool) -> bool -> bool
```

`f b` has to be of type `bool`, and therefore `f` is `'a -> bool` and `b` has type `'a`. `f`, of type `'a -> bool` has the same type as `fun x -> b` which is `'c -> 'a`. So, `'c = 'a = bool`, so `bf` takes `bool`, then the type of `f` which is `bool -> bool`, and returns `bool -> bool`, for a final type of

```
bool -> (bool -> bool) -> bool -> bool
```

I have to find the type of

```
let t1 = apply bf
```

which is the same type as `apply bf`.

So, `apply f` is `'a -> 'a` if `f` has type `'a`, so I'd expect `apply bf` to have `type(bf) -> type(bf)` which would be

```
bool -> (bool -> bool) -> bool -> bool -> bool -> (bool -> bool) -> bool -> bool
```

Apparently `apply bf` is of type `bool -> (bool -> bool) -> bool -> bool` and I don't get why that's the case.

I also don't get the difference between an `'a` type and an `'_a` type.

If `let apply f x = f x`, then `apply` has type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`, and `let app2 = apply apply` has type

```
('_a -> '_b) -> '_a -> '_b
```

If someone could help me understand why that's so, so that I don't feel lost in simply submitting the answers without understanding it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd expect apply bf to have type(bf) -> type(bf)

This is wrong. First note that the typing rule for application is,

```
f   : A -> B
x   : A
-------------
f x : B
```

In your case there's polymorphism at play but the idea is the same,

```
apply    : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b)
bf       :   A -> B
------------------------------------
apply    : (A -> B) -> (A -> B)
bf       :  A -> B
------------------------------------
apply bf :  A -> B
```

> I also don't get the difference between an 'a type and an '_a type.

The notation `'_a` represents a dummy type, and a consequence of the "value  restriction" which states only value expressions can be polymorphic. See http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction

Comment: Another way of describing `_a` is that it represents an arbitrary type, but only one specific type. I.e., it's a monomorphic type variable. This mechanism allows more flexibility than simply rejecting code that violates the value restriction.

Comment: Thank you. What about this other function: ``let w f x = x (f x)``.

I get that ``f x`` has type ``B``, ``x`` has type ``A``, and thus ``f`` has type ``A -> B``.

Yet, then ``x`` has to also be of type ``B -> C`` since it takes ``B`` on the righthand side, meaning that ``A`` = ``B -> C``, so ``f`` is really of type ``B -> C -> B``.

``w`` is of type ``((a -> b) -> a) -> (a -> b) -> b``. That would've matched, if it weird for the fact that ``a`` is something larger. I don't know how to derive that. Another instance I found was ``(a -> (b -> a)) -> b -> a -> b``, but that's no good.

Comment: Then you have `f : A -> B` and `x : C -> D` since both are functions. Since `x` is an input of `f` in `f x` then `A = C -> D`. And since `f x` is an  input of `x` then `B = C`. So we have `f : (C -> D) ->C` and `x : C -> D`. So  `w : ((C -> D) -> C) -> (C -> D) -> D`.